# Hibernate set property access strategy on whole Spring Boot application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

as I know Hibernate provides two access strategy: FIELD and PROPERTY. It is possible to define it by setting anotation `@Access` above entity, but it is a little bit frustrating to set every time `@Access` with strategy during implementation. Is there any way to set access strategy "global" on the whole of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such a property exists in Spring Boot by default.

However, you can create a parent class for all your entities to define `@AccessType` at the class level just once.

**Documentation**

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf

> **2.3.1 Default Access Type** (Page 23)
>
> By default, a single access type (field or property access) applies to
>   an entity hierarchy. The default access type of an entity hierarchy is
>   determined by the placement of mapping annotations on the attributes
>   of the entity classes and mapped superclasses of the entity hierarchy
>   that do not explicitly specify an access type.

**Example**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent { 
}

@Entity
public class Child extends Parent {
    ...
}
```