# Set Hibernate access strategy globally?

Tags: java, hibernate

According to the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access), the placement of the `@Id` annotation determines how Hibernate will access the entity (field or accessors)

> As a JPA provider, Hibernate can introspect both the entity attributes (instance fields) or the accessors (instance properties). By default, the placement of the @Id annotation gives the default access strategy. When placed on a field, Hibernate will assume field-based access. Place on the identifier getter, Hibernate will use property-based access.

Is it possible to define this globally via a property (To avoid having to place a `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` on each entity or embeddable)?

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228550/hibernate-set-property-access-strategy-on-whole-spring-boot-application), but that is for Spring Boot specifically.

Comment: Could you explain why do you need this? Why you can't just put `@Id` in a proper place?

Comment: Can't you just use a the same strategy in the related question you mentioned? Having an access type in a parent class and extending this class for all entities seems like a general solution.

Comment: I mostly want it for the `@Embeddable` objects I have where there is no id. IntelliJ shows the getters with a red underline, unless I add `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` on each object. I would like to do this globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called `orm.xml` and put it to the classpath in directory `META-INF`.

In that file you can set default values. For example the access type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
            <access>PROPERTY</access>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

You can find the XML Schema here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/resources/org/hibernate/jpa/orm_2_2.xsd